# If found brackets found in string, then remove brackets and data inside brackets

Tags: python, regex

I would like to detect brackets in a string, and if found, remove the brackets and all data in the brackets

e.g.

`Developer (12)`

would become

`Developer`

Edit: Note that the string will be a different length/text each time, and the brackets will not always be present.

I can detect the brackets using something like

```
if '(' in mystring: 
   print 'found it'
```

but how would I remove the `(12)`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice

Comment: You should probably use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: `slice(0, myString.index('('))`

Comment: Are the brackets always in the end fo the string? Do you need to take care of nested brackets?

Comment: @SebastianProske yes always at the end, no nested.

Comment: @Franco OK, the problem is much simpler then. The proposed answers work, but a regexp is not even needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user regex and replace it:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '','Developer (12)')
'Developer '
>>> a='DEf (asd () . as ( as ssdd (12334))'
>>> re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '','DEf (asd () . as ( as ssdd (12334))')
'DEf  . as )'
```

Comment: @S.deMelo from the op - _"yes always at the end, no nested."_. He clearly states that he does not need to support nested brackets.

Comment: @leaf It wasn't the case at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this

```
import re
a = "developer (12)"
print(re.sub("\(.*\)", "", a))
```

Comment: This is identical to the previous solution and has the same limitation

Comment: @brianpck I posted it without seeing the previous answer, but yes its similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's always at the end and there is no nested brackets:

```
s = "Developer (12)"
s[:s.index('(')]  # or s.index(' (') if you want to get rid of the previous space too
```

Answer (score 0):

For nested brackets and multiple pairs in string this solution would work

```
def replace_parenthesis_with_empty_str(str):
    new_str = ""
    stack = []
    in_bracker = False
    for c in str :
        if c == '(' :
            stack.append(c)
            in_bracker = True
            continue
        else:
            if in_bracker == True:
                if c == ')' :
                    stack.pop()
                if not len(stack):
                    in_bracker = False
            else :
                new_str += c
    return new_str

a = "fsdf(ds fOsf(fs)sdfs f(sdfsd)sd fsdf)c  sdsds (sdsd)"
print(replace_parenthesis_with_empty_str(a))
```